# Make two genymotion Android emulator work in one SAME WiFi work

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, genymotion, lan

I am developing an Android file sharing APP in WiFi LAN.

Therefore I'd like to make my two genymotion emulator(in one host Windows PC) work in the same WiFi network, but in default these two emulator have both 10.10.3.15 as local IP, which means in different network.

So is there any possibilities or solutions to make it?

Comment: See if this helps: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#connecting

Comment: @MatanItzhak That does help if connection of certain ports is needed，  however I am looking for making these two virtual machine works link in the same LAN and they could send broadcast and setup a socket connection between undefined ports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup your two Virtual Device in bridge mode as explained here https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/03_Virtual_Devices/Managing_virtual_devices/Configuring_a_virtual_device.htm

The 2 devices will request an IP on your LAN dhcp and will be accessible like any other device in your network

Comment: It works fantastically, I could even detect the virtual machine from my real cell phone in the real WiFi netwok!